# Android Bitmap - Replace an object's color keeping Anti-Aliasing

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, antialiasing, alpha-transparency

I have an image in my assets folder on which I am drawing stuff using an external program and then using them in my app. The problem is that the bitmaps are blank (transparent) with black and white objects in them. Note that the objects are created with Anti-Aliasing on to look better. I know this was asked before but I couldn't find what I want. I need to replace all the black  and white pixels in the image (**even the transparent anti-aliased ones!**) to the colors given by the user. Below are some images to show what I want to do:

[image: Example of image transformation]

Please note that this is just an example and I have even some very complicated shapes and the final colors aren't known (as inputed by the user in RGB style).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can tint the images you load apliying them a color at runtime. 
The problem is that color applies to the whole image and it only matchs exactly the same color in white pixels, with or without alpha.
So you could separate all the areas of the image with the same color, save them as white and then tint them at runtime while overlapping one over another.
It depends on the framework you are using.

Comment: It says in the tags of the question (Android). I'm not very sure how to make all pixels same with only alpha differing but I think for black / white this shouldn't be a problem, so right now I only want to know how to do this. So this isn't really an answer, it doesn't solve my problems...

Comment: With the framework I'm using right now (kivy), for the image of your example, I would save 2 images PNG (photoshop, without background), with the areas I want to tint in white. Then I would place them over the screen overlapping, and assigning them different colors. Problably is not the fastest way, but it works. You may have tools to achieve it in your framework, don`t know